# A drag-and-drop file upload Javascript library

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am looking for a JavaScript drag-and-drop file upload library like minus.com here

[image]

A drag-and-drop should trigger uploading right away.

I understand there is a decent jQuery library http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ but I would like one triggering uploading right away

Comment: Mmmm, have you checked here? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone bumps into this, here is what you're looking for:  http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://niklr.github.io/angular-material-datatransfer/

It uses Angular Material as UI component framework and offers features such as:

- Upload and download of multiple simultaneous files
- Upload in small chunks to support large files
- Drag and drop
- Pagination
- Customizable look
- Fault-tolerance by automatically retrying
- Export results to CSV or JSON

The application is explicitly designed for modern browsers supporting advanced HTML5 File API features.